# Debugging spplot() and reflconv() on R Cannot allocate vector of size ...?

Tags: raster, r, rgdal

I am trying to perform LANSAT data of Digital Numbers (DN) to reflectance in R(coding) using reflconv().

When I apply that function to example it shows below error:

```
>library(rgdal)   
x <- readGDAL("LC81370452014329LGN00_B5.TIF") 
// LC81370452014329LGN00_B5.TIF has GDAL driver GTiff and has 
7891 rows   and 7711 columns

 >spplot(x) 
// Error : cannot allocate vector of size 232.1 Mb

>reflconv(x,2.0000E-05,-0.100000)
//Error : cannot allocate vector of size 464.2 Mb
```

What is the cause of this error?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I have seen the [link] (https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2012-January/013944.html) I am also facing same problem

Comment: Can you suggest any R code related to my question , it will be helpful to me thanks

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with a clearer statement of what you are trying to do, precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck.  I strongly recommend taking the [Tour] which you appear to have not yet done because it provides an excellent overview of how the site works.

Comment: Are you using a 32 bit version of R? Have you read the answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171593/r-memory-management-cannot-allocate-vector-of-size-n-mb ?

Comment: yes i am using 32 bit and R is of 3.2 version

Comment: service pack 3 ,windows xp,3.25 of RAM

Answer (score 1):

try

```
library(raster)
spplot(raster("LC81370452014329LGN00_B5.TIF"))
```

the `spplot` method for `RasterLayer` objects does not try to read & plot all pixels, as opposed to the `spplot` method in `sp`, which does.